# PHP regex to fetch the inner function list from JavaScript source code

Tags: php, regex, regex-group, preg-match-all, inner-function

Below is the JavaScript source code on which the php regex I am trying to apply.

```
<script>
function outerfunction () {

    function abcd () {
        return ('efgh', 1);
    }

    function efgh () {
        return ('higk', 2);
    }
}
</script>
```

I am trying to fetch all the inner function from the JavaScript code below with function name length having 4 chars, using `preg_match_all()` with pattern `/(function.[a-z]{4}.[(][)].*)}/s`. using this online tool [phpliveregex.com](https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-match-all)

below is the output in 2nd array. but i need all the functions list as in individual array elements. currently it is comming inside single array element result.
[image: php regex output]

Current output

```
array[1] => function abcd () {
        return ('efgh', 1);
    }

    function efgh () {
        return ('higk', 2);
    }
```

Needed:

```
array[1] => function abcd () {
        return ('efgh', 1);
    }

array[2] => function efgh () {
        return ('higk', 2);
    }
```

Comment: What if those inner functions have inner functions themselves?

Comment: good question, need to think if so. but there is no such scenario as of now.

Comment: do you need to account for `arrow functions` too?

Comment: Where the correct answer posted yesterday is gone? Did the author or moderator deleted it?